# Parsing an XML file in which some records(xml) are split across multiple lines?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

There is a code deployed which parses xml file line by line but at a times xml file contains record(xml) which  is split across different line how to tackle that because deployed code uses readline() function of python therefore there is an error when the record(xml input) is split across multiple lines as a result there is unclosed token issue. So we have to delete that record. Is there any approach which can solve the problem.

No error

```html
<SegmentTag> "Data is present in one line" </SegmentTag>
```

Error related to unclosed even if the tags are closed but present in multiple lines. How to parse these type of records without changing readline() function.

```html
<SegmentTag> "Data is spread across 
multiple lines..." </SegmentTag>
```

Comment: The code should NOT read the xml line by line. It should used a library like ElementTree for the parsing

Comment: Spaces and Returns are allowable in innertex for XML so there is nothing wrong.  An XML library should be used for this type of issue.

Comment: @balderman size of xml file is around 1GB that's why we are reading it line by line. And at each  line there is one xml tree complete but in some case that is spit across multiple lines because of which  we are getting error. So you have any insights on this.

Comment: Use SAX API in order to deal with the file size.

Comment: Thanks @balderman will go through SAX API.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to read XML as ordinary text: always use an XML parser.

Comment: Thanks but to make it more clear, We are reading one line of xml file and parsing it because single is sufficient in itself to be a complete xml tree but at a times that particular line is split across multiple lines because of which we are getting parsing error because tags will not be closed properly if we read one line and try to parse it as it is closed in next line.

Comment: Classic design mistake. You've chosen a design approach that works on your initial dataset and doesn't extend to the general case. Which is precisely why you should have been using a real XML parser from the start.